# create java model from json data

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a json data (that i can't change) stored in my nosql Mongodb database.
This is how the data looks like :

```
{"scans" : {
        "Bkav" : {
            "detected" : false,
            "version" : "1.3.0.4924",
            "result" : null,
            "update" : "20140214"
        },
        "MicroWorld" : {
            "detected" : false,
            "version" : "12.0.250.0",
            "result" : null,
            "update" : "20140216"
        },
        "nProtect" : {
            "detected" : false,
            "version" : "2014-02-16.01",
            "result" : null,
            "update" : "20140216"
        }
  }
}
```

what i'm trying to do is to create a rest webservice based on spring boot in order to retrieve the data stored in mongo, so i need to set up my models (based on the json format ) and this is what i came up with :

```
public class Scans
{
    @Id
    private String id; 
    private Bkav Bkav;
    private NProtect nProtect;
    private MicroWorld-eScan MicroWorld-eScan;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Bkav = "+Bkav+", nProtect = "+nProtect+", MicroWorld-eScan = "+MicroWorld-eScan+"]";
    }
 }
```

And for each scanner (Bkav, nProtect, MicroWorld-escan) i have this same model :

```
public class "scanner" //that may be one of the above names;
{
    private String update;
    private String result;
    private String detected;
    private String version;
    //getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [update = "+update+", result = "+result+", detected = "+detected+", version = "+version+"]";
    }
}
```

So is it possible to create only one class for all the scanners since i have more than the ones i listed in my question

Comment: I think your JSON needs to be deserialized into a `Map<String, Scanner>`

Answer (score 1):

First, `MicroWorld-eScan` is not a valid class or variable name

In my experience, you would need to have this model

```
public class Scans {
    @Id
    private transient String id; 
    private TreeMap<String, Scanner> scans;

    // for example
    public Bkav getBkav() {
        return map.get("Bkav");
    }
```

I would recommend a different name to not conflict with `java.util.Scanner`